# DB2 on Docker :: IBM Data Studio prompts error when creating new database

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5, db2-9.7, ibm-data-studio

I've followed [this simple guide](https://ajstorm.medium.com/installing-db2-on-your-coffee-break-5be1d811b052) and I was able to install DB2 on Docker.

I now would like to import a [sample database](https://dataedo.com/kb/databases/db2/sample-databases) to play with.

So I open IBM Data Studio, I right click on the instance > New database... , I fill up with my user name and password but then an error appears:

> The system cannot verify the instance that you specified. Either enter
> a valid instance name or click on the button next to the Instance name
> field and select one from the list.
> com.ibm.datatools.adm.explorer.ui.model.InstanceException: An internal
> error occurred during: "Verifying instance db2inst1 in system
> 192.168.1.44.".

[image]

If I expand the error for more details I see:

> 'Verifying instance db2inst1 in system 192.168.1.44.' has encountered
> a problem.
>
> An internal error occurred during: "Verifying instance db2inst1 in
> system 192.168.1.44.".
>
> An internal error occurred during: "Verifying instance db2inst1 in
> system 192.168.1.44.".
>
> com.ibm.db2.das.core.DasMessageIdentifier (initialization failure)

[image]

A dive in the official documentation brings me to [this solution](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-installation-completes-error-error-occurred-while-creating-instance-db2inst1-return-code-1) but I don't think that could be the problem.

What intrigues me is the 'dot' (`.`) after the IP address. Could this be the error?

[image]

Or is there any other way to import a sample database from IBM Data Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to create a sample database is to login to the container:

```
~]$ docker exec -ti mydb2 bash -c "su - db2inst1"
```

Once inside the container:

```
[db2inst1@e88eefa89d92 ~]$ db2sampl 

Creating database "SAMPLE"...
Connecting to database "SAMPLE"...
Creating tables and data in schema "DB2INST1"...
Creating tables with XML columns and XML data in schema "DB2INST1"...

'db2sampl' processing complete.

[db2inst1@e88eefa89d92 ~]$ db2 list db directory

System Database Directory

Number of entries in the directory = 1

Database 1 entry:

Database alias                       = SAMPLE
Database name                        = SAMPLE
Local database directory             = /database/data
Database release level               = 15.00
Comment                              =
Directory entry type                 = Indirect
Catalog database partition number    = 0
Alternate server hostname            =
Alternate server port number         =
```

If you don't want to use the sample database provided via db2sampl, you can create a database as part of the start of the container via `-e DBNAME=MYSAMPLE`:

```
docker run -itd --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=whatever  ibmcom/db2 -e DBNAME=MYSAMPLE
```

Now you can try to connect to that database from data studio, setup your tables and inserting data.

Comment: Thank you @Lennart, what do you think about the dot?

Comment: I have not used Data Studio, so I'm afraid I don't know what it looks like when it's working.

Comment: Do you use another GUI client or you just import databases from .sql files form command line? I'm asking because I'm testing the performances. Creating the SAMPLE database took minutes and I already tested that on 2 different machines. I'm talking about DB2 into a docker container

Comment: It becomes to long for a comment, I'll update my answer